# C++ Array and if loop. If loop ignoring values and giving wrong lines when value is input

Tags: c++

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
double Num1, Num2, Num3, Num4, Num5, Num6, Num7, Num8, Num9, Num10, Num11, Num12;
int StudentID;


 Num1= 97 * 0.3;
 Num2= 79 * 0.3;
 Num3= 86 * 0.4;
 Num4= 91 * 0.3;
 Num5= 78 * 0.3;
 Num6= 79 * 0.4;
 Num7= 73 * 0.3;
 Num8= 77 * 0.3;
 Num9= 82 * 0.4;
 Num10= Num1 + Num2 + Num3;
 Num11= Num4 + Num5 + Num6;
 Num12= Num7 + Num8 + Num9;

 cout << "Please enter a Student ID "<< endl;
 cin >> StudentID;
 {
 if (StudentID= 2046)
    cout << "The grade for student " << StudentID << " is: " << Num10 << endl;


else if (StudentID= 7634)
    cout << "The grade for student " << StudentID << " is: " << Num11 << endl;


else if (StudentID= 8120)
    cout << "The grade for student " << StudentID << " is: " << Num12 << endl;

else if (StudentID != 2046, 7634, 8120)
    cout << "I'm sorry that is not a valid StudentID " << endl;
}



return 0;
}
```

Needed output (when 2046 is input): 
Student id: 2046
Grade for student is 87.2

Output received:
Student id: 2046
Grade for student is 87.2
I'm sorry that is not a valid id

What might the issue here be? Sorry if it's obvious I'm kind of a novice coder.

Comment: `StudentID != 2046, 7634, 8120` ... do you know what the `,` means here? Anyhow you simply need an `else` in place of that last `else if`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the Comma Operator work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work)

Comment: `if (StudentID= 2046)` should be `if (StudentID == 2046)` - you're assigning the value 2046 to `StudentID` and then testing the result (same in a few other places)

Comment: If someone types "banana" as their student ID, older versions of C++ would not assign StudentID to anything - meaning attempting to read it is undefined behaviour.  You could resolve this by either assigning a value to StudentID in its declaration (like you did with Num1 & others...) or by checking the cin error bit

Comment: Upvoting because OP tried and posted a fairly minimal piece of code that demonstrated the problem

Answer (score 2):

This condition:

```
if (StudentID = 2046)
```

always evaluates to `true` because the expression of `StudentID = 2046` uses an [assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment) and (the entire expression) is always implicitly converted to `true`. It does not check if `StudentID` is equal to `2046`. For that you need to use the [equal to](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison) operator that is `==`:

```
if (StudentID == 2046)
```

This condition:

```
if (StudentID != 2046, 7634, 8120)
```

is a comma separated expression that evaluates to the right-most value which is `8120` which is implicitly convertible to `true`. It does not check if the `StudentID` is not equal to all the listed numbers. To do that you would need to store the values inside a `std::vector`, `std::array` or similar and check if it matches any of them.